# Check if the form is submited does not work

Tags: php

I want to echo something once a form is submitted. But when I click the submit button, it seems that the page is just refreshing itself and I do not see the word that I have written in the echo section.  Here is my code:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    echo "submitted";
}

?>
<h3>Post your form here</h3>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <label>Insert a title here</label><br>
    <input name="title" type="text" placeholder="add a title"><br><br>
    <label>Insert the body here</label><br>
    <textarea name="body" placeholder="insert the body here "></textarea><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"><br>
</form>
```

I also tried the code by removing the isset function, but that did not work, either.

Answer (score 2):

In form action, you have missed an echo.

`action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"`

Comment: I just tried the exact code and worked fine. Can you enable errors and see if you can get any errors?
`error_reporting(E_ALL);`
`ini_set("display_errors", "On");`

Comment: Just after the starting `<?php` tag. `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", "On"); ......`

Comment: I does not give me any errors but it does not show anything either. Please look at the answer that I have given to this question, the port number was incorrect. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is working code. I test it on my Machine.
Why you don't use else statement to test it better.
here is the code. 
Note (Check your localhost server settings)

```
 <?php 
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
   echo "submitted";
   }
 else
 {
    echo "Not working";
  }
?>

 <h3>Post your form here</h3>
 <form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  <label>Insert a title here</label><br>
  <input name="title" type="text" placeholder="add a title"><br><br>
  <label>Insert the body here</label><br>
  <textarea name="body" placeholder="insert the body here "></textarea><br>
  <br>
   <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"><br>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the credit goes to @ashok. He was right that I needed to check  localhost server settings. 
I am using Phpstorm to write PHP codes. Whenever I click on the Chrome browser to see the results, it takes me to

```
http://localhost:63342/ name of the file page.
```

The port 63342 is the default port used by Phpstorm. Since I am using Xampp and it runs on port 8080. I changed port number 63342  to 8080, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting to the same page, you really dont need to define an action.

Instead of `isset`, use `!empty` as such

```
if(!empty($_POST['submit'])){
echo "success";
}
```

I must bring to your attention that if the suggestions don't work, you should start with debugging what you are actually receiving from the form POST, using:

```
<pre>
<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>
</pre>
```

Turning on error reporting in your php settings is also a good start for debugging.